# Execute a Stored Procedure with different missing parameter calls

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

If I have a stored procedure like this:

```
CREATE Procedure [dbo].[insertIntoTableX]
    -- table_name as there are three tables with the same schema...
    @table_name varchar(200),
    -- all the other variables for the columns
    @column_1 = NULL,
    @column_2 = NULL,
    @column_3 = NULL,
    @column_4 = NULL,
    @column_5 = NULL
AS
BEGIN TRY
  SET NOCOUNT ON

  INSERT INTO @table_name (column_1, column_2, column_3, column_4, column_5)
  VALUES (@column_1, @column_2, @column_3, @column_4, @column_5)
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  -- ....
END CATCH
```

If I call it with `Execute insertIntoTableX (1,2,3,4)`, the results will be [`1`,`2`,`3`,`4`,`NULL`] because the fifth was set to null by the default values in the stored procedures.

How do I call it with a missing parameter? E.g. if want the result to be [`NULL`,`NULL`,`3`,`NULL`,`5`]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would call the stored procedure with named parameters.  For instance:

```
exec [dbo].[insertIntoTableX] @column_3 = 3, @column_5 = 5;
```